# What's the difference between data fetching when I refresh or when going to the page with navigation?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

So, I have this component `results.js`, in this component I fetch data from our Back-end server.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Navigation from '../../components/Navigation';

const Results = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      {console.log(props)}   
    </div>
  )

}


export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  // Fetch all the id's
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.myapi.com/results`)
  const results = await res.json()
  return { props: { results } }
}
```

And I have this navigation

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link as="/" href="/"><div>Homepage</div></Link>
            <Link as={`/results`} href={`/results`}><div>ResultsPage</div></Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navigation;
```

My question comes now:

Why is it that when I refresh, it does my call but it can't be seen in the network developers console?

And why is it not when I go with the navigation to the page, in my developers console?

example when i Refresh:

[image]

example when I using navigation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when using Server Side Rendering, the initial page, served when you first access a page inside the website (or refresh the current page), is rendered on the server, so the server is making that request for you. However, after the initial page loads, the app behaves like a normal SPA, so the navigation and the rendering of that page (including making the request to the API) is done on on the client.

Comment: Oh, alright, thanks! Do you know how I can make the request on the serverside when going to the page with the navigation?

Comment: I don't know if that makes sense, since that data is probably used to render some components. However, you may be able to proxy the API using the backend. I'm not that familiar with Next.JS so can't help with that unfortunately.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I don't want people to have acces to my data through the network console. and I thought, if it doesn't show when you get the data on the server, then I need to always fetch it on the server.